In-place operation in a for loop using pytorch
I'm trying to train a model to compute a parameter ("param"). I'm expecting a value of this param for each timestep (range(1, 3) in the code below).
But I'm getting the error:
RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.

Here a simplified version of my function:
import torch

def function(input_tensor, param):
    result = torch.zeros((3, 3), requires_grad=True)
    result[0] = input_tensor
    
    for i in range(1, 3):
        result[i] = param * result[i-1]  
    
    return result


input_tensor = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], requires_grad=True)
param = torch.tensor(2.0, requires_grad=True)


output = function(input_tensor, param)


loss = output.sum()
loss.backward()


You can't perform an in-place operation on a variable that requires gradient calculation. This is because gradients are assigned to variables, so mutating a variable in-place breaks the computational graph.
In this case, the variable in question is result and the in-place operation is result[i] = param * result[i-1].
You need to compute the result using without using in-place operations. For the example you gave, you can do the following:
def function(input_tensor, param, steps):
    pow_indices = torch.arange(steps).view(-1, 1)
    powers = torch.pow(param, pow_indices)
    result = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0) * powers
    return result

input_tensor = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], requires_grad=True)
param = torch.tensor(2.0, requires_grad=True)
output = function(input_tensor, param, 3)
loss = output.sum()
loss.backward()

